# Каким образом git сохраняет изменившуюся строку при коммите?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-add

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться!
При замене части одной строки с последующим коммитом, gitk, gitg отображают нечто похожее на:

```
-Длинная строка версии 1
+Длинная строка версии 2
```

А сам git работает со строками, или данный вывод только для удобства пользователя? Как же тогда с бинарными данными? То есть можно записать несколько короче, что строка изменилась в таком-то месте.

Comment: git по разному работает с текстовыми и бинарными файлами.

Comment: с текстовыми построчно, с бинарными -- нет

Comment: Насколько я понял, git не наблюдает за изменениями подстрок и при малейшем изменении считает новой именно строку?

Comment: @andreysv Это особенность не `git diff`, а формата [`unified diff`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) вообще.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Есть две важных особенности Git:

1. Git сохраняет содержимое файлов при выполнении `git add`, а не `git commit`
2. Git не имеет такого объекта как дельты/патчи/изменения файлов, он работает со снимками (snapshots) файлов, которые были добавлены в индекс из рабочей области.

   - Однако на уровне хранилища дельты используются, об этом в параграфе 3.2.

> А сам git работает со строками, или данный вывод только для удобства пользователя?

Git сравнивает целые файлы, но показывает только те строки, которые изменились. То, что вы видите, выполняя `git diff ...` - это результат работы инструмента [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility). (спасибо [Котик_хочет_кушать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4149/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) за ссылку).

### 1. Как файлы добавляются в индекс (stage)

Команда [`git add`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431839/181472) (и `git commit -a`, которая неявно вызывает `git add`) создает объекты двух типов и связывает их в [направленный ациклический граф](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84):

1. **Листья (blob)** — объекты, соответствующие файлам проекта.

   - Можно считать, что они являются бинарными архивами этих файлов.
   - В обычном режиме для одного файла создается один объект типа лист.
   - Для текстовых файлов возможно исключение: `git add --patch <filename>`
   - Буквально переводится как «капля» или «шарик». Термин заимствован из баз данных, где [BLOB это Binary Large OBject](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLOB).
2. **Деревья (tree)** — объекты, соответствующие директориям проекта.

   - Каждое дерево содержит другие деревья и/или листья.
   - Для корневой директории создается единственный корневой объект–дерево.
   - Дерево не может быть пустым, т.е. ничего не содержать. Поэтому [в Git нельзя добавить пустую директорию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437311/181472).
   - Не путайте с веткой — в Git это совершенно иная концепция.

### 2. Как создается коммит

Все коммиты также хранятся в виде направленного ациклического графа. 
Команда `git commit` только формирует объект коммита из уже готовых данных, которые содержатся в индексе. Вот как она это делает:

1. Создается корневой объект типа **commit**, который получает ссылку на корневой объект-дерево, хранящийся в индексе.
2. После создания графа к коммиту добавляется метаинформация (автор, дата и т.п.).
3. Коммит получает ссылку на родительский коммит и таким образом включается в граф коммитов.
4. Ветка (которая является просто плавающим указателем) перемещается на вновь созданный коммит.
5. Индекс очищается и ждет новой команды `git add.`

### 3. Как сохраняются изменения файлов в истории коммитов

#### 3.1. На концептуальном уровне: цельные снимки

Повторю, что с точки зрения пользователя, коммиты представляются как цельные снимки, а не дельты/патчи относительно друг друга.

На этой иллюстрации: с пунктирным контуром — переиспользуемые версии файлов из прошлого коммита, с целым контуром — новые версии файлов, которые сохраняются в листьях и включаются в дерево нового коммита.

Впрочем, это плохая иллюстрация. Со временем я добавлю хорошую. Напомните мне, если я забуду.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробнее в Pro Git ([на английском](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics), [на русском](http://www.git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git)).

#### 3.2. На функциональном уровне: сжатие через дельты

([Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198276/2790048), авторы [Jan Hudec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/201725/jan-hudec) и [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc), спасибо [Eugene Ryabtsev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188165/eugene-ryabtsev) за ссылку).

**Git использует дельты, но только для хранения данных в своем внутреннем формате.** Более того, это реализовано гораздо эффективнее, чем в любой другой VCS. Git хранит дельты листьев. При сохранении нового листа Git выбирает другие, наиболее близкие к нему, генерирует дельты и выбирает наименьшую. Таким образом он может использовать листья от похожих файлов или более ранних версий этого же, которые ближе по содержанию. Внутренний параметр "pack window" отвечает за баланс между производительностью и эффективностью сжатия дельт. Значение по умолчанию (10) обычно дает удоволетворительные результаты. Но для того, чтобы сэкономить место или ускорить передачу репозитория по сети, можно использовать `git gc --aggressive`. Эта команда работает со значением pack window = 250; она выполняется очень долго, но обеспечивает более высокое сжатие данных.

Подробнее о сжатии дельт: [Matthew McCullough, Git Compression of Blobs and Packfiles](https://gist.github.com/matthewmccullough/2695758).

Comment: Уже ответил и только потом заметил, что это некропост. Эх.

Comment: *Напомните мне, если я забуду*

Comment: Напомните мне, если я забуду))

Comment: *Напомните мне, если я забуду*

Comment: *Напомните мне, если я забуду*