# Как гит осуществляет хранение данных?

Tags: git

Читая про гит, втсречаешь вот такие картинки:

[image]

[image]

Как и где гит осуществляет хранение всех этих данных?

Comment: В файлах хранит.

Comment: `.git/objects`?

Comment: А какого вопроса этот является дубликатом? Ничего не показывается. Я бы предложил вот этот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425121/181472