# Как создать (добавить) директорию?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-add

Первый день работаю с GIT (BitBucket).

Возник вопрос как создать и закоммитить директорию.
Добавил в основную папку проекта (на локале) директорию. Потом в терминале написал:

```
git add *
git push
```

и в итоге ничего не изменилось. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: если директория пустая, то ее добавить нельзя. Так задумано. Если директорию все же нужно добавить, то в не создается пустой файл с именем вида `.touch`, `.gitkeep`, `.do_not_remove`.

Comment: ручками это все делается(файл тоже приходиться ручками впихивать?-ибо при попытке запихнуть в добавленную папку файл, он ругался на то что это не возможно). а через терминал можно как-то все сделать? я имею ввиду начиная от создания папки и заканчивая пулом.

Comment: @DarkVss: через терминал можно сделать все ))) сейчас в ответ добавлю.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь,ребята=)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Чтобы git сохранил директорию:

1. Она должна быть непустой.
2. Нужно добавить её содержимое и сделать коммит.

## 1. Директория должна быть непустой

- Добавить пустую директорию нельзя. Команда `git add` «видит» только файлы и пути, в которых они лежат.
- Чтобы сохранить пустую директорию, создайте в ней пустой файл `.gitkeep` и добавьте его в git.

### Почему git так работает?

Потому что он хранит данные в виде следующих объектов:

- Blob, блоб (от Binary Large OBject) — бинарный архив файла.
- Tree, дерево — текстовый список содержимого директории: файлов (блобов) и других директорий (деревьев).

Дерево не может быть пустым — by design, так устроен алгоритм. Поэтому пустую директорию нельзя добавить. Чтобы её наполнить, достаточно создать в ней файл. Обычно такой файл называют `.gitkeep`, но допустимо любое имя.

Например, в директории есть файл и ещё пара директорий, одна из которых пуста. Вот что будет после команды `git add .`:

```
на диске:       в индексе git:
.               tree
├── dir1        tree
│   └── file1   blob
├── dir2        (ничего)
└── file2       blob
```

Чтобы узнать про другие объекты и подробности, читайте [Git from the bottom up](http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf).

## 2. Нужно сделать коммит

Команда `git add` только добавляет файлы в индекс, после чего нужно сохранить их командой `git commit`.

Для добавления [используйте `git add .`, а не `*`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431839/181472).

Comment: 1)как потом подняться обратно? 2)как убрать следующее-после создания файла открывается консольный редактор.там что-то пишешь,если закрыть-все стереться.как сохранить не понятно... объясните пожалуйста если не сложно

Comment: @DarkVss: если Vim, то выйти из него: Esc — :wq — Enter. Подробнее: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30710567/2790048

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а у нас есть где-нибудь вопрос+ответ, компактно раскрывающий суть *stage area/index*?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, возможно, имеет смысл разложить на несколько вопросов. про саму концепцию («промежуточный аэродром», в отличие от *stash* — «запасного аэродрома») отдельно, про работу с ним (добавление файлов, патчей, удаление файлов, патчей) — отдельно. может быть, даже ещё мельче, если получится.

Comment: vim,но чего-то не работает нормально или я тупой просто...а в место него можно повесить что-то более демократичное?(на мест о редактора,например блокнот?)))))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, наверно, пора. сейчас попробую сделать.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, могу удалить. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26116/git--ru-so

Answer (score 4):

Добавьте файл `.gitkeep` (или любой другой) в Вашу директорию которая должна быть закомичена

Answer (score 2):

чтобы добавить подпапку (с файлами проекта) на контроль версий:

```
git add folder_name/
```

далее что вам нужно, git commit. git push....