# Какие изменения происходят на удаленном сервере при git push?

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

Если я делаю push из локального репозитория в удаленный, то на удаленном файл полностью изменяется на локальный? Или они сначала сравниваются и заливаются только изменения?

Comment: Что попало в гит, то останется в гите :)

Comment: @o2gy: ну, всегда можно filter-branch сделать или ещё что похлеще )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git оперирует не файлами, а коммитами.

Коммит — это «снимок» текущего состояния рабочей области. Он содержит полные версии файлов, а не изменения (также называемые дельтами или патчами).

Подробнее о коммитах: [Каким образом git сохраняет изменившуюся строку при коммите?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/126895/181472)

> Или они сначала сравниваются и заливаются только изменения?

Отчасти вы правы: они действительно сначала сравниваются. Для сравнения файлов используется алгоритм [Secure Hash Algorithm](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1). Когда вы заливаете (push) очередные коммиты на удаленный сервер, Git сравнивает значение sha1 для каждого объекта. Если в его истории уже есть объект для этого значения, то повторно закачиваться он не будет. Если нет — то будет закачана полная версия этого файла, а точнее, содержащий его объект типа blob.

> на удаленном файл

Как уже отметил alexander barakin, ваш удаленный сервер скорее всего типа bare, то есть не содержит файлов в рабочей области (а только внутренние файлы Git-репозитория).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А если, скажем, мы с другом делаем один проект, работает над одним файлом. Затем я делаю push, заливаю файл. Он ведь уже не сможет сделать push без предварительного pull? И если он сделает pull, то его файл (вместе с его наработками) заменится моим?

Comment: Верно, сделать push без pull он не сможет. А когда он сделает pull, то возможны варианты: либо git сможет самостоятельно решить конфликты при выполнении git pull (например, вы с товарищем правили разные части файла) - тогда у товарища останутся и его изменения, и будут свежие ваши. Либо git не сможет решить конфликты (вы правили одну и ту же часть файла), тогда товарищ увидит что-то вроде *error: Your local changes to 'path/to/file' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.*. В этом случае,если он не хочет потерять свои изменения,то будет вынужден сделать *commit* или *stash* и решить конфликт

Comment: @АлексейКожарин: вам тут ответил o2gy, прочитайте.

Comment: @АлексейКожарин: При попытке сделать pull у друга произойдет конфликт слияния на каждом файле, который изменили **вы оба**. Если только один отредактировал свой файл, а у другого – изначальная версия, то автоматически будет выбрана новая, измененная. Подробнее о разрешении конфликтов слияния (там про локальные ветки, но разницы никакой нет): http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/437458/181472

Comment: спасибо! что-то я напутал - решил, что автор вопроса всегда получает уведомления о комментариях... Еще, как бы запомнить, что здесь `enter` означает "отправить комментарий", а не перевод строки )

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! Получается, мы с другом можем спокойно работать даже над одним и тем же файлом, если делаем изменения в разных частях кода, так?

Comment: @АлексейКожарин: можете, но конфликт будете разрешать потом вручную. Читайте ответ по ссылке о том, как это делать вручную. Если можете, то лучше редактируйте разные, несвязанные файлы.

Comment: @АлексейКожарин:  кстати, если ответ вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста, примите его (галочка рядом с ответом)

Answer (score 2):

удалённый репозиторий — скорее всего — *bare*-репозиторий («голый»), т.е. **возле него** нет *рабочего каталога* (*working directory*), и, соответственно, никаких файлов, которые вы наблюдаете в **своём** *рабочем каталоге*.

---

чтобы было понятней: в удалённом репозитории хранится практически то же, что и у вас в каталоге `.git` **возле** содержимого вашего *рабочего каталога*.

а это, собственно, и есть *git*-репозиторий.

---

исходя из вышеизложенного, надеюсь, становится понятно, что вопрос в текущей формулировке просто лишён смысла.