# Как правильно опубликовать проект, содержащий базу данных?

Tags: база-данных, git, github, веб-программирование

Часто на собеседованиях или перед ними просят показать какой-нибудь свой код. Я хочу написать для этих целей какой-нибудь небольшой проект и разместить его например на GitHub.

Предполагаю, что это будет небольшое веб-приложение, работающее с базой данных. Но если не ошибаюсь то на GitHub нельзя просто так взять и залить базу данных. А хотелось бы, чтобы потенциальный работодатель мог получить ссылку на репозиторий и увидеть пример работающего приложения.

Скажите пожалуйста как можно залить бд на GitHub, чтобы любой человек при желании мог целиком собрать рабочее приложение? Или  может есть другие способы? Спасибо!

Comment: Я немного расширил формулировку вашего вопроса, чтобы он не подпадал под [проблему молотка](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/181472).

Comment: Меня забанят за рекламу (не своего проекта, что отчасти оправдывает)). Есть механизм для деплоя, написанный на питоне: [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). У него есть дополнение [fabtools](http://fabtools.readthedocs.org), при помощи которого можно удаленно создать базу, пользователя в нем и добавить какие-угодно записи. Но вам, скорее всего, достаточно будет написать sql-скрипты, которые сгенерируют нужную структуру БД + инструкция по тому, как и что разворачивать. Можно и самому написать небольшой скрипт для авторазворачивания, это не сложно, главное - инструкции ))

Comment: @BOPOH: как раз об этом написал, но у меня абстрактные рассуждения, а у вас — ссылки на готовые инструменты. Думаю, банить тут не за что. Предлагаю опубликовать как ответ.

Comment: Если один из вариантов вас устроил, вы можете его принять (галочка рядом с ответом). Если нет — задавайте уточняющие вопросы в комментариях.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

вероятно, бо́льшая часть [систем управления базами данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) обладает возможностью сделать *dump* базы данных, содержащий всю необходимую информацию для последующего воссоздания базы.

причём, как правило, такой *dump* сохраняется в текстовом виде, т.е. представляет собой неплохой объект для систем управления версиями, которые лучше всего «обращаются» именно с текстовой информацией.

---

некоторые *субд* могут даже предоставлять специальные опции для улучшения такого рода хранения (в системах управления версиями).

например, у программы `mysqldump` есть опция `--skip-extended-insert`, благодаря которой в *dump*-е генерируется отдельный оператор `insert` для **каждой** строки данных. без неё все строки таблицы заносятся одним, очень-очень длинным оператором `insert`, что, естественно, создаёт определённые трудности для, например, сравнения отличий между двумя *dump*-ами.

Comment: спасибо за --skip-extended-insert, не знал

Answer (score 3):

В принципе, в репозитории Git можно сохранить что угодно, в том числе бинарные файлы базы данных. Но [Git хранит целые файлы, а не дельты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425121/181472). И тем более он не сможет сохранять изменения в том виде, в котором его воспринимают СУБД. Т.е.

Для СУБД:

> Найти поле X, записать в него значение Y
>
> - изменение в несколько байт.
> - старая версия удаляется

Для Git:

> Полностью удалить файл и заменить его новым.
>
> - изменение в много мегабайт
> - все версии сохраняются.

Таким образом, если вы будете сохранять в коммитах последовательно несколько состояний БД, то каждое будет целиком и навсегда сохранено в репозитории. Это очень быстро раздует его размеры.

**Что было бы лучше:**

1. написать SQL / DDL код, инициализирующий базу данных в том виде, в котором она нужна для работы приложения
2. Написать инструкцию по установке или скрипт для автоматизации установки (плюс в глазах работодателя)
3. Публиковать в репозитории этот код и документацию (ну и само приложение).

**Вариант 2:**

Опубликовать проект одним коммитом, без истории.

**Ссылки:**

- [Хранение схемы MySQL в репозитории Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5518349/2790048) (eng)

Answer (score 2):

Храните в репозитории только структуру и миграции, а дамп с данными (не думаю что у вас большая база) залейте в релизы на github или на bintray, и укажите ссылку на базу в описании README.MD

Answer (score 2):

Способ, который будет удобен даже в production, и который выставит вас в выгодном свете, будучи применённым в демо:

1. Создаёте дамп структуры базы данных. Как уже было сказано, это текстовый файл. В структуре базы имеет смысл указать версию этой структуры (например, создать представление с одним селектом одной константы).
2. Создаёте дамп тестового набора данных. Тоже текстовый файл, с INSERT'ами.
3. (Опционально) Создаёте скрипт, обновляющий старую структуру базы до новой, на основании информации о версии структуры.
4. Создаёте программу, каким-то образом имеющую параметры подключения к серверу и имя БД. При запуске программа подключается к серверу, проверяет версию сервера, смотрит есть ли БД. Если старая версия сервера - откланивается. Если нет базы - предлагает создать (с помощью скрипта; если выбрана галочка внесения в базу тестовых данных, то следом вносятся тестовые данные). Если старая версия структуры - предлагает обновить (с помощью скрипта).
5. Далее программа работает как обычно.

При веб-разработке, "программа" это скорее всего страница в "/admin".

Answer (score 1):

Ответ очень сильно зависит от платформы, которую вы используете.

Если вы (случайно) пишете на C#/.NET, то на гитхаб можно просто так взять и залить базу данных - mdf/ldf файлы с подключением в приложение через AttachDbFileName в строке соединения. В заданных рамках - выложить куда-то пример своего кода, который можно будет забрать/показать/запустить без лишних телодвижений - это более чем подходящее решение.

Если вы при этом еще и используете Entity Framework Code First - то ваше приложение и так уже умеет создавать базу данных, и ничего никуда заливать не нужно.

На всякий случай стоит использовать имя сервера (localdb)\v11.0 в обоих вариантах - этот инстанс с большой вероятностью есть на машине с Visual Studio, и приложение можно будет запустить сразу после скачивания исходников.

Answer (score 1):

База данных может быть построена по стандарту [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org/). Физически это обычные директории ("наборы данных") и json-ки в них. Соответственно, отлично будет работать прямо в склонированном репо.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала Вам необходимо выгрузить текущее состояние базы данных в виде дампа сриптов описания сущьностей, и затем придумать каким образом это всё менеджить в Вашей системе контроля версий.

Мне нравится подход описанный в блоге [Scott Allen](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/01/31/versioning-databases-the-baseline.aspx)

В кратце, создаётся *baseline* - папка начального состояния с дампами описаниями структуры таблиц. Среди Ваших таблиц создаётся таблица для журнала версий к примеру **SchemaChanges**. В этой таблице будут отображаться изменения произведённые уже на данной БД.

После такой подготовки создаётся папка изменений БД в которую вносятся изменения существующей схемы. Каждое изменение схемы должно добавлять свою версию в журнал изменений.

Для работы с другими сущьностями БД как *view*, *trigger*, хранимые процедуры и функции Скот предлагает сделать для них отдельную папку и накатывать их после каждого изменения структуры бд, тем самым проверяя не нарушилось ли состояние базы.

Достаточно сложно, но тем не менее достаточно стабильно и не требует особо больших усилий, кроме как для написания утилиты для запуска скриптов.
Более подробно и на русском можно [почитать перевод](http://lshnk.me/tag/schema-migration.html).

Сейчас достаточно много платных утилит призвано решить эту проблему к примеру утилиты [red gate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) или [apexsql](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_source_control.aspx).

Ищите подход который больше подходит Вам.