# Можно ли хранить базу MySQL в git и обновлять её на сервере?

Tags: mysql, git, github

Отлаживаюсь на локальной машине и пару раз в день обновляю сервак... Файлы я просто перезаливаю с локальной, хотя могу использовать git, выйгрыша пока особого не вижу...

А вот можно ли обновлять базу MySQL с помощью Git? Иногда добавляю таблицы, поля и т.д.. При этом информация в базе на сервере постоянно пополняется...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно опубликовать проект, содержащий базу данных?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/443119/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону миграций, как это сделано, например, в yii фреймворке. Где есть возможность как накатить, так и откатить изменения (на случай появления ошибок) в БД.

Тогда достаточно просто заливать на сервер только файлы с миграциями и исполнять, когда необходимо

Answer (score 0):

можно хранить в репозитории **дамп** базы данных.

у *mysql* есть опция `--skip-extended-insert`, помогающая создать дамп [удобного для контроля версий формата](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443130/178576)