# Как синхронизировать базы данных?

Tags: mysql

Товарищи программисты! Подскажите пожалуйста, как синхронизировать изменения в mysql на локальном компьютере c базой данных на хостинге. Я через phpmyadmin делаю дамп локальной БД, и загружаю его через такой же на хостинге, предварительно очистив ту базу. Но это всё долго. Существуют ли какие-нибудь решения, позволяющие это делать в один клик?

Comment: Поделюсь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454196/191482

Comment: Если важно изменять структуру базы данных - смотрите в сторону механизма миграций, если в вам важно изменять данные - в сторону репликации.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать php-скрипт который будет проверять изменения в таблицах, например по id и в случае отличия добавлять новые записи в бд на хостинге.