# Возможно ли через git копирование на внешний жесткий диск

Tags: git, резервное-копирование

Хочу организовать домашние хранение исходников. И интересует следующий вопрос:

Могу ли я настроить git таким образом, что бы он работал с github и внешним жестким диском (или флешкой) одновременно. При этом жесткий должен выступать своего рода бэкап хранилищем с которого можно обычным копированием взять любую сохраненную версию.

Например если я проталкиваю изменения, то на жестком в определеной папке создается папка (а еще лучше сжатый архив) с именем проекта и датой внесения и в это папку (или архив) заносится полная копия текущей версии проекта.

**PS:** В git я новичок, поэтому вопрос может быть банальным, но меня интересует возможно ли это в принципе сделать именно средствами git.

Если это возможно сделать, то буду признателен если напишете приблизительно описание как это можно реализовать.

Операционка - windows.

Comment: Если речь идёт о том чтобы взять с собой только актуальную версию проекта, то совсем не обязательно мучатся с настройками системам управления версиями. Гораздо проще скопировать нужные файлы и папки с ПК или просто выгрузить актуальную версию из репозитория Git на флешку либо внешний ЖД.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Лучший способ делать бэкап репозитория Git — это репозиторий Git (как ни странно).

Копировать в архивы и папки — плохо и неэффективно. Во-первых, вы таким образом ломаете всю идею и делаете очень неудобные в использовании бэкапы. Во-вторых, Git [очень эффективно хранит свои данные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/425121/181472) и простой архив вам такой эффективности не предоставит.

Предлагаю такой способ: сделать локальный bare репозиторий и обновлять в него.

### Делаем резервную копию

Пример: репозиторий у нас лежит в `~/repo`. Резервную копию мы будем создавать в `~/backup`.

```
$ mkdir ~/backup
$ cd ~/backup
$ git clone --mirror --no-hardlinks ~/repo
```

После этого в папке `~/backup/repo.git` будет создан bare-репозиторий. Обратите внимание, что папка не просто `.git`, а `repo.git`. Параметр `--mirror` делает следующее.

- Включает в себя параметр `--bare` — cделать репозиторий голым (bare). Такой репозиторий хранит только файлы Git и не хранит обычные файлы в рабочей области (в резервной копии они нам не нужны)
- Заставляет Git копировать все ветки (branches), метки (tags) и другое. [Подробнее в документации](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

Параметр `--no-hardlinks` нужен для того, чтобы Git не пытался сэкономить место, делая хардлинки вместо прямого копирования файлов. Для резервной копии хардлинки не годятся.

### Обновляем резервную копию

Теперь мы можем подключить эту резервную копию как remote и в нее делать push.

```
$ cd ~/repo
$ git remote add backup ~/backup/repo.git
$ git push backup --all
```

Либо заходить в папку резервной копии и там делать update

```
$ cd ~/repo
$ git --git-dir=~/backup/repo.git remote update
```

Параметром `--git-dir` мы явно указываем Git, где искать его директорию. Сам не найдет, т.к. имя нестандартное.

### Восстанавливаемся из резервной копии

Разумеется,  для этого понадобится Git. Если совсем нет возможности его установить, попробуйте [Git Portable](https://github.com/sheabunge/GitPortable) от sheabunge.

#### Вместе с репозиторием

> обычным копированием взять любую сохраненную версию.

Чтобы достать сохраненную версию из нашего резервного репозитория:

```
cd ~/new-repo
git clone ~/backup/repo.git .
git pull --all
```

Теперь у нас есть полная копия того репозитория + версия рабочей области из последнего коммита в master. Можем получить любое другое сохраненное состояние:

```
git checkout <revision-sha1>
```

#### Только файлы из резервной копии

```
git --git-dir=~/backup/repo.git --work-tree=куда/положить/файлы checkout
```

Параметр `--work-tree` указывает Git путь, который он будет считать своей рабочей областью на время выполнения текущей команды. Путь должен существовать (т.е. Git не будет создавать его сам).

#### Только файлы из рабочего репозитория

```
cd ~/repo
git --work-tree=куда/положить/файлы checkout
```

Git просто скопирует текущее состояние рабочей области туда, куда нужно.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, этот метод не позволит работать с бэкапом на компе без git?

Comment: @Vasek: Верно, это бэкап исключительно для Git. Bare-repo — это форма, в которой репозиторий хранится на GitHub и любом другом сервере. Чтобы развернуть его на машине без Git, можете использовать например [Git Portable](https://github.com/sheabunge/GitPortable). Но если вы хотите сделать копию просто для работы с ней на другом компе — это скорее не бэкап, а обычная копия. Кстати, и в этом случае эффективнее всего делать `git clone`, только не локального репозитория, а на GitHub.

Comment: @Vasek: обновил инструкцию про то, как восстанавливаться из бэкапа.

Comment: @Vasek: кстати, еще есть [git archive](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-archive)

Comment: git archive имено то что нужно)

Comment: @Vasek: ха)) ладно, перепишу ответ про archive, а бэкапы — отдельным опубликую.

Comment: В строке `git --git-dir=wiki.git remote update` разве не должно быть `git --git-dir=~/backup/repo.git remote update`?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов точно, ошибка. Предложите правку? )

Comment: @ГерманБорисов спасибо )

Answer (score 3):

Вам потребуется использовать хуки (hooks) и ознакомиться с [особенностями использования хуков в windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277429/executing-git-hooks-on-windows), [вопросы по теме.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows%20git%20hooks), возможно поможет [эта статья](http://forworktests.blogspot.ru/2013/02/git-pre-commit-hook-windows.html).

Answer (score -1):

Git я пока не использую, но проекты скачиваю регулярно. Чтобы скачать репозиторий одного проекта, открываю нужный мне репозиторий, на данное время уже в самом сайте github реализована кнопка "Code" - при щелчке (click) из нее выпадает список-меню:
1)Open with GitHub Desktop
2)Download ZIP
Выбираю 2-й пункт - закачивается весь проект с директориями и файлами в виде zip-файла. Далее все просто - распаковыаем и  используем как вам угодно.

Comment: к вопросу данный «ответ» отношения не имеет.