# Git дома и в офисе через флешку

Tags: git

Есть проект над которым работа ведется в офисе и из дома. Осваиваю гит. 
Как грамотно синхронизировать коммиты, при условии связи только через флешку?

Comment: кратко: нужно использовать флешку как bare-репозиторий. Подробнее напишу чуть позже.

Comment: Вот эта инструкция вам должна подойти: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448242/181472. Создавайте репозиторий на флешке и носите её между домом и офисом.

Comment: Если не подходит — напишите, почему. Пока что я отмечаю, что ответ есть в другом вопросе.

Comment: Ну как, получилось?