# Сократится ли размер репозитория на GitHub, если удалить из него часть данных?

Tags: git, github

Если залить репозиторий до 400МБ, а потом удалить часть и оставить до 50МБ. То общий **размер репозитория будет всеравно 400МБ?** Ну чтобы востановить снимок тех 350МБ их же надо где-то хранить.

Вопрос связан с ограничениями размера репозиториев в частности GitHub.

Comment: а 400 мегабайт - это сорцы или общий размер папки?

Comment: @KoVadim получается есть разница? я только начинаю использовать гит после svn

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону git squash

Comment: естественно есть. Гит хранит локальную копию репозитория (в скрытой папке .git). И даже, если все сорцы удалить и закоммитить, то размер уменьшиться ровно на размер сорцов за вычетом некоторый внутренний структур гита (инфу о удалении нужно сохранить)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Естественно, если данные можно восстановить, то значит где-то они лежат.

Гит хранит разницы между состояниями файловой системы. Так что в вашем примере будет примерно так:

```
+400мб   - залили файлы (не принимая в расчет сжимающиеся они или нет)
+0,001мб - залили инфо о том что файлов больше нет
```

Более подробно, о том как гит обращается с коммитами вы можете прочитать здесь:
[Каким образом git сохраняет изменившуюся строку при коммите?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/126895)

Comment: `Гит хранит разницы между версиями,` (c) а в книге написано категорически другое. Кому верить вам или книге разработчиков?)

Comment: гит хранит "снимки файловой системы на каждый конкретный коммит".

Comment: @KoVadim Всегда считал, что git **дает доступ** к снимкам "файловой системы на каждый конкретный коммит", а как он их внутри хранит его личное дело, и хранение разниц - самый эффективный вариант. См. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105 примечание к первому ответу.

Comment: разница не самый эффектнивный вариант ( в некоторых случаях). Например, если файл "сильно переписали", то diff (разница) может быть больше файла.

Comment: @KoVadim Разницу можно считать по разному, например в этом случае - все строки в 1 были удалены, все строки во 2 добавлены, будет почти равнозначно замене файла. Оставим это в "деталях реализации" )

Comment: Верить надо официально документации https://git-scm.com/documentation и в ней написано как раз что гит в отличии от svn хранит не изменения, а полностью снимок фс

Comment: @Mira: Повторюсь, git дает доступ к снимкам "файловой системы на каждый конкретный коммит", а как он их внутри хранит его личное дело, и хранение разниц - самый эффективный вариант. Еще раз, это внутренняя организация хранения, и она никоим образом не подрывает идеологию гита хранить снимки, без информации о том как прошли изменения. Предлагаю вам проверить, залив в репозиторий файл 1мб, и пролить десять раз изменения по 1 байту. Посмотрите, станет ли репозиторий занимать 10мб.

Comment: @Mira Как оказалось, по крайней мере TortoiseGit, достаточно глуп, и действительно сохраняет весь упакованый файл в котором прошли изменения. Таким образом залив в репо несколько 700кб txt, каждое изменение в 1 файле прибавляет репозиторию по 100кб.

Comment: @KromStern Так это ж одно из основных отличий гита, его фишка . в частности раздел в документации так и называется "слепки вместо патчей" и там речь имено о хранении а не представлении данных( https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git )

Comment: @Mira Тем не менее, хранятся разницы (на уровне файлов). Если изменился 1 файл, то ревизия содержит только его, а не весь слепок с остальными файлами/папками? Проверьте

Comment: Если копнуть глубже, то храниться все так: измененные файлы сохраняются в каталоге .git, а потом создается файл "дерева", где указаны хеши этих измененных файлов и ссылка на родительское дерево. Как результат - не нужно хранить список "всех файлов".

Comment: Да можно не проверять :) это тоже в той же доке есть - что если файл не изменен - то хранится ссылка на предыдущий. Я все к тому что все написано в документации и ей стоит верить в первую очередь

Comment: "Доверяй, но проверяй" как говорится :)

Comment: Вообще с этим интересная ситуация. То, как себя ведут некоторые команды, заставляют считать, что коммит по смыслу это набор изменений. При этом внутри он представляет собой полные состояния файлов **поначалу**, но впоследствии они разностно сжимаются в основу и изменения для неё. [Подробнее](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-Pack-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B).